# Strange issues with AP and printers on network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dhcp, switch

i have a TpLink WA901ND using it as access point, connected to a simple 8 ports switch and one of these ports is connected to a network printer.

```
My Access point has this class of ip: 
IP: 192.168.11.254 
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
DNS: 192.168.11.254
DHCP enabled with this range: 192.168.11.100 - 192.168.11.199
My printer has this class of ip:
IP: 192.168.11.233 
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
And i've tried to assign the gateway of the printer in this combination:        192.168.11.254 (AP), 192.168.11.233 (The self printer ip)
```

By the way, nothing worked, I mean, if i'll connect via cable to my switch everything works like a charm, but, unfortunately, if I connect to my wifi, i cannot see anything, no ping, no netcat, nothing of nothing.

Comment: anything, please advise!

Answer (score 0):

> If I connect to my wifi, i cannot see anything

There's a feature called AP isolation that would do this - its meant for security, but in this case, you can turn it off